# ASP.NET Core serialized object with a FileInfo returns incomplete JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project with a controller whose GET method returns an object that contains a `System.IO.FileInfo` property.  When I call the API (e.g. in a web browser), it returns an incomplete JSON string.

Here's the class whose instance is getting serialized:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FileInfo File { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the controller, program, and startup classes:

```
[Route("Test/Home")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Thing>> GetThing()
    {
        return new Thing()
        {
            Name = "First thing",
            File = new FileInfo("c:\file.txt")
        };
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
        => await CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<Thing>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Here's the URL:

```
https://localhost:44381/Test/Home
```

And the result I'm getting:

```
{"$id":"1","name":"First thing","file":
```

So why is the JSON string incomplete, breaking off at the `FileInfo` object?  [`FileInfo` is serializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-2.2).

Here is the full project if you want to try it yourself:

https://github.com/roryap/FileInfoAspNetCoreIssue

All the references I've found that cover this sort of thing, like the ones below, talk about EF Core and cyclical references, which is obviously not the case here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365960/2704659

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54633487/2704659

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49224944/2704659

Comment: Json.NET doesn't use .NET's serialization infrastructure. Even then, serializing a `FileInfo` object serializes the object itself, not the contents of the file it points to.

Comment: What's the point of exposing a FileInfo instance in your model ? Why not just have a string property containing the file / directory name / contents ?

Comment: @auburg  irrelevant.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- Yes I know it obviously doesn't serialize the contents of the file.

Comment: @rory.ap it's *very* relevant. If you check [the ISerializable implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesysteminfo.cs,334) a FileInfo object will write out the `OriginalPath` and `FullPath` properties to the `SerializationInfo` object. JSON.NET doesn't use `ISerializable` though, so it should try to write out all of `FileInfo`'s properties. Somehow, somewhere that fails

Comment: Interesting, and maybe I'm wrong. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new FileInfo(@"c:\moo.txt"))` creates `{"OriginalPath":"c:\\moo.txt","FullPath":"c:\\moo.txt"}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos -- It was directed at auburg's comment.  I want to know about the observed behavior -- why i'm not just making my own set of properties is not relevant to my question.

Comment: I think it has to do with fileinfo not having a parameterless constructor. Im gonna get lunch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem here seems to be that the [documentation for `FileInfo` in netcore-2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-2.2) is just wrong -- `FileInfo` is not, in fact, marked with [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) in .Net core.  Without `[Serializable]`, Json.NET will try to serialize the public properties of `FileInfo` rather than its [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable) data, eventually leading to a stack overflow exception on at least one of the properties, `FileInfo.Directory.Root.Root...`.  The returned JSON then gets truncated at the point the exception is thrown, as the server had already started writing the response at that point.

(In fact it appears that `FileInfo` is blacklisted on .Net core to avoid the stack overflow, see [Issue #1541: StackOverflowException when serializing DirectoryInfo object on dotnet core 2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1541#issuecomment-354637802).  A custom exception is thrown instead.)

To confirm the documentation error, the [reference source for .Net core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileInfo.cs#L18) (mirrored [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/FileInfo.cs,16)) shows `FileInfo` to be declared as follows (while declared as `partial` it appears to have only one file):

```
// Class for creating FileStream objects, and some basic file management
// routines such as Delete, etc.
public sealed partial class FileInfo : FileSystemInfo
{
```

While the [reference source for the full framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,34) shows the following:

```
// Class for creating FileStream objects, and some basic file management
// routines such as Delete, etc.
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class FileInfo: FileSystemInfo
{
```

Lacking the `[Serializable]` attribute, Json.NET will ignore the `ISerializable` interface on the base class as explained in the Json.NET 11 [release notes](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more):

> - Change - Types that implement ISerializable but don't have [SerializableAttribute] are not serialized using ISerializable

So, what can be done?  One possibility would be to create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that forces `FileInfo` to be serialized using the `ISerializable` interface:

```
public class FileInfoContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(FileInfo))
        {
            return CreateISerializableContract(objectType);
        }

        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Configure the contract resolver as shown in, e.g., *[Setting JsonConvert.DefaultSettings asp net core 2.0 not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46360651/3744182)*.

Another possibility would be to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `FileInfo` that serializes and deserializes the same properties as the full framework does:

```
public class ISerializableJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : ISerializable
{
    // Simplified from 
    //  - JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable()
    //    https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1708
    //  - JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeISerializable()
    //    https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L837
    // By James Newton-King http://james.newtonking.com/
    // Not implemented: 
    // PreserveReferencesHandling, TypeNameHandling, ReferenceLoopHandling, NullValueHandling   

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));

        SerializationInfo serializationInfo = new SerializationInfo(objectType, new JsonFormatterConverter(serializer));

        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    serializationInfo.AddValue((string)reader.Value, JToken.ReadFrom(reader.ReadToContentAndAssert())); 
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}", reader.TokenType));
            }
        }

        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new object[] { serializationInfo, serializer.Context }, serializer.Culture);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var serializable = (ISerializable)value;

        SerializationInfo serializationInfo = new SerializationInfo(value.GetType(), new FormatterConverter());
        serializable.GetObjectData(serializationInfo, serializer.Context);

        writer.WriteStartObject();

        foreach (SerializationEntry serializationEntry in serializationInfo)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName(serializationEntry.Name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, serializationEntry.Value);
        }

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        return reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();
    }

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

internal class JsonFormatterConverter : IFormatterConverter
{
    //Adapted and simplified from 
    // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/FormatterConverter.cs
    // By James Newton-King http://james.newtonking.com/
    JsonSerializer serializer;

    public JsonFormatterConverter(JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        this.serializer = serializer;
    }

    private T GetTokenValue<T>(object value)
    {
        JValue v = (JValue)value;
        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(v.Value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (!(value is JToken))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value is not a JToken.", "value");
        }

        return ((JToken)value).ToObject(type, serializer);
    }

    public object Convert(object value, TypeCode typeCode)
    {
        if (value is JValue)
        {
            value = ((JValue)value).Value;
        }

        return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeCode, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public bool ToBoolean(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<bool>(value);
    }

    public byte ToByte(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<byte>(value);
    }

    public char ToChar(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<char>(value);
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<DateTime>(value);
    }

    public decimal ToDecimal(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<decimal>(value);
    }

    public double ToDouble(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<double>(value);
    }

    public short ToInt16(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<short>(value);
    }

    public int ToInt32(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<int>(value);
    }

    public long ToInt64(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<long>(value);
    }

    public sbyte ToSByte(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<sbyte>(value);
    }

    public float ToSingle(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<float>(value);
    }

    public string ToString(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<string>(value);
    }

    public ushort ToUInt16(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<ushort>(value);
    }

    public uint ToUInt32(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<uint>(value);
    }

    public ulong ToUInt64(object value)
    {
        return GetTokenValue<ulong>(value);
    }
}
```

And then add `new ISerializableJsonConverter<FileInfo>()` to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).

Notes:

- For details on why Json.NET ignores `ISerializable` when a given type lacks the serializable attribute, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881884/3744182) to *[Deserializing custom exceptions in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50845255/3744182)*.
- You may want to [statically cache the contract resolver for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).
- Serialization via `ISerializable` may not work in situations of partial trust.
- Note that [asp.net-core-3.0](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-3.0) is set to use a [completely different JSON serializer](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/90) out of the box, so some additional configuration work will be required to use this answer there.  For details see *[Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55666826/3744182)*.